# Car Stereo and separate clock keep resetting when car is turned off

Tags: electrical, audio

Car Stereo and separate clock keep resetting when car is turned off. 
I bought recently a 2005 Kia Spectra. Car had several previous owners. Stereo is aftermarket pioneer. The stock clock in the car also resets every time car is turned off. I first thought it might be a previous faulty stereo installation but now I realize the dome lights will also turn off when car is turned off (Like right the way) and power locks do not work either when car is turned off. Basically the key has to be switched to acc in order to have anything electric working in the car. Any ideas?

Comment: It sounds as though the Body Control Module (or whatever Kia calls it) has gone out. The BCM controls all of these functions, to include any residual power which occurs after the key is turned off, but before a door is opened or 15 minutes, whichever occurs first. I'm not sure how Kia handles this, so leaving it as a comment.

Comment: Hi Paulster. It was actually a fuse but I am still having problems. There is a fuse that controls that a 15a blue in a slot called room. It is usually removed during long periods of inactivity to diminish chances of battery drainage. The stereo has a beautiful colorful light display that does not turn off when stereo is turned off. the stereo display is still on even after removing the key of ignition and opening the door. I think is wired wrong because you can even turn radio back on with no need of key in ignition. That will drain battery but i dont know how to fix it.

Comment: There are usually two power wires going to an aftermarket stereo. One is full power, the other keeps all the settings, but doesn't allow turn on. Sounds like these were either mixed up, or the second wasn't installed correctly. First should be switched power. Second should be full time.

Comment: I see that they are both the red for the main power and the yellow from memory are both connected together to 2 cables coming from the car (one red orangish and one pink or fuchsia (pastel purpleish) hard to tell them apart . The genius that made the installation butchered the car's harness out of the picture...so the 4 cables are crimped together I think.

Comment: Figure out which is switched coming from the car. The yellow one from the stereo should be the full time power.

Comment: It may be a feature. Some cars may turn off stereo/accessories when you lock the doors. Does it still stay on after you lock doors? One of the cabling related responses may also be right, you may have incorrectly wired stereo.